# Is that possible to use bun.sh with Plesk?

Tags: passenger, plesk, phusion, bun

I would like to use bun.sh with Plesk, is that possible to add manually or should we wait Plesk Devs?

[image]

Checked forums and Plesk community manager says "There is no support for bun yet"

Regards.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Currently it is not possible. Plesk has a feature request "bun". You can vote for it. That will make it more likely that Plesk adds the feature: https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/47176689-bun